# What is the best practice for searching in a large SQLite database?

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, search

We have a large database of about 3 million records using SQLite. Now we want to be able to search the database and search for occurrences of the terms in all the columns. We have a table company with a few fields:

```
EnterpriceNumber  ||  Denomination  ||  Country  ||  Street  ||  HouseNumber  ||  Zipcode  ||  Snippet
```

An example of one of the records could be:

```
12345678  ||  Company B.V. ||  Netherlands  ||  Examplestreet  ||  25  ||  000AA  ||  Example company, located in the Netherlands.
```

Now we're building an API and want to let users of our system search for multiple columns in one query. One of the queries could be `Examplestreet 25`, `Company B.V. Examplestreet 25` or `0000AA 25`.

Our current query looks something like this. Of course it's looking in all the columns, so this is a smaller version.

```
SELECT * FROM company
    WHERE (Denomination LIKE '%keyword%')
    OR (Street LIKE '%keyword%');
```

However the above search queries would result in nothing with the above query. **How would be able to achieve this? Or what would be the best practice for searching in this database?** I've been reading about virtual tables but I'm not too sure how we can use it in our application / database.

Thanks for looking into this thread

Comment: Check out [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

Comment: How's the perfomance if these temp.tables are created on every search? Wouldn't it fill up?

Comment: Why temporary ?

Comment: I've looked a lot more into the subject and it seems like the best option. The database has doubled in size, but the search results and times are a lot better!